# str_replace with array_keys/array_values returns strange result

Tags: php, str-replace

For some odd reason, below function returns `11` when input `2`, where I would expect it to return `1`. What is wrong?

```
<?php 
function convert($v){

  $arr = array(
    2 => 1,
    21 => 1,

    3 => 2,
    6 => 2,
    11 => 2,
    12 => 2,

    4 => 3,
    14 => 3,
    19 => 3,

    9 => 5,

    1 => 11,
    10 => 11,

    22 => 12,
    23 => 13,
    14 => 14,
    );

  $ret = str_replace(array_keys($arr), array_values($arr), $v);
  return $ret;

}

echo convert(2); // echoes 11

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong function, try [`strtr`](http://php.net/strtr) instead:

```
function convert($v){

  $arr = array(
    2 => 1,
    21 => 1,
    ...
    23 => 13,
    14 => 14,
    );

  $ret = strtr($v, $arr);
  return $ret;

}
```

And in any case: If you find something strange with a PHP function, visit it's manual page and read it, for [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace) a specific example is given that explains your problem: [Example #2 Examples of potential str_replace() gotchas](http://php.net/str_replace#example-4479)

Comment: You're welcome, I think every PHP programmer did this mistake once ;)

Answer (score 3):

This is because `str_replace()` processes each replacement from left to right. So when it matches on the key `2` in your array, it is changed to a `1`. After that, it hits the key `1` and is changed to an `11`. As a short example:

```
function convert($v) {

    $arr = array(
        1 => 2,
        2 => 3,
        3 => 'cat',
    );

    $ret = str_replace(array_keys($arr), array_values($arr), $v);
    return $ret;
}

echo convert(1); //cat is echoed
```

So in this case the `1` goes to a `2`, then that `2` to a `3`, and finally the `3` to `cat`.